# Get touch pressure for Android using js react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I would like to know please how to get touch pressure using react native, in other words, how much pressure the user puts with his finger when touching the screen. I know it's possible using Android for capacitive touchscreens, but how to do it using react native.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touchable Opacity , Touchable Highlight, Touchable Native Feedback like components..
You can refer this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_touches.htm

Comment: I konw this, in my question I said I want to get a pressure value when the user touches the screen, in other words, how much pressure he puts with his finger when touching the screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build functionality like this on React Native
Most recent Api for handling touches (Pressable) can detect long press, but no how much pressure

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

But if it's implemented natively in Android, you can use native code in React Native and implement it.